# Annoying delay before i can click a button after open an XPage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

when I open an XPage with a lot of ssjs in it. I have always the problem, that when I click a button (with ssjs in it) directly after opening the page, nothing happens. When I wait 1 or 2 seconds, every thing works as expected. It seems, that not everything is loaded fast enough.

Is there an event to see if the document is completly loaded? I tried the jquery and dojo onready events and as well the onClientLoad event. But all these events trigert directly after the page is open (but not finish loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault. I just recognized that there are more than 30 panels there all have an empty onClientLoad method in it. After I removed the events, my page need to load 500ms insted of 2,5s and also the XSP.addOnLoad event to see if the page is ready now works as expected.

Thanks @Serdar Basegmez for your help.

Comment: Finding this could also help fix the view issue in your previous question, if this is on the same XPage.

Comment: Sadly this problem is in another page, that haven't this event problem. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following onClientLoad event as a client side javascript:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(new function() {
// this will run when everything is ready...
});
```

That's also why you see a lag for button events. All event handlers are binded via the same mechanism as above.

Comment: i add this in a scriptBlock to my document...but it also fires the event directly after opening the document and not when the document is ready.

Comment: The problem with the script block, your injected code will run **before** other onLoad functions that prepares all event handlings. How many components do you have in the page? Normally user should not notice such a time difference between onLoad and the binding.

Comment: There are a lot components, and some of the code is probably not optimized. But where shut i add the XPS.addOnLoad?

Comment: Goto the events tab of the XPage, select onClientLoad event, select Client and write into the script editor.

Comment: hmm...makes no diffence...Is there a way to prioritize the binding?

Comment: Then, there must be something else slowing down the binding process. I have created hundreds of components with a server-side binding and it gets loaded and ready in a few milliseconds. I suggest checking the page using firebug or a similar utility to see the load sequence. Net panel or could be useful in such cases.